# Read only file system on linux embedded device

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I am using Qt to write an app to deploy to an embedded Linux device. My dev computer is a vm running Ubuntu and it communicates with the embedded device over ethernet and rs232. Qt has a section to go and set up the communication lines between the two and test them and they seem ok.

But when I deploy to the embedded device, I get this error:

```
mkdir: can't create directory '/opt/Evo2a/': Read-only file system
```

the error is in reference to the embedded device.

Is there a toggle in Linux to make the file system "writeable"?

Comment: This is very much specific to your embedded device. You *might* be able to just remount read/write (`mount -o remount,rw`), but that might cause something else to fail later.

Comment: Do you have access to it, like ssh? Add the content of `/etc/fstab` please.

Comment: As already mentioned, it very much depends on the embedded device, but also keep in mind that many embedded devices use a read-only compressed file system, and sometimes an overlay file system to store configuration files etc. If your embedded device has any way to use external storage (e.g. via the network), deploying your app for testing in this would reduce the number of writes on the embedded device.